# How to link google account when using gspread and python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-account, gspread

I am trying to use gpread with python to edit google spreadsheets. I followed this tutorial: http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html
When I run my code, it says that there is no module named oauth2client.client. Do I need to install something else to make it work?

**Update**
here is my code:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('GraduationCash-c4b4c0667c75.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("Where is the money Lebowski?").sheet1

raw_input()
```

Also i should mention that I am on windows 8, so those commands are not working. it is still saying that there is no crypto library avalible

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)! This is not nearly enough information for us to help you. Can you update the question with your code (or better yet, a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example)) and the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must install OAuth client [library](https://github.com/google/oauth2client):

```
$ pip install --upgrade oauth2client
```

Of course, you always can install from source, also well:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google/oauth2client 
$ cd oauth2client 
$ python setup.py install
```

**Note**
After intall if you get a error like "*No crypto library available*":

```
$ apt-get install python-openssl
```

or

```
$ pip install PyOpenSSL
```

Comment: ok, I installed the oauth library, but now I am getting another error. It says that there is no crypto library available.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, I've used GoogleCredentials.

I had success with the following code below. I had to create an account on the Google Developer site [here](https://console.developers.google.com/). From there, go to API Manager > Google Apps API >  Drive API, then Enable API. Then select Credentials > New Credentials > Service account key. At this point, download the key as JSON and store it somewhere secure. Copy the email address in the JSON file and add it to the sheet you want to access.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
credentials = credentials.create_scoped(['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'])
gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet = gs.open('Testing').worksheet('Sheet1')

list_of_lists = sheet.get_all_values()

print(list_of_lists)
```